# While json_decode i want duplicate key values also in array PHP

Tags: arrays, json

I want to have the JSON below as an array with duplicated key values, i.e.:

```
"2016-09-16":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"}
```

twice. How can I do that?

```
{
    "2016-06-28": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-06-29": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-06-30": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-07-04": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-07-05": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-07-06": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-07-07": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-16": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-15": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-14": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-13": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-16": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    },
    "2016-09-17": {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

JSON with duplicate keys in the same object is not reliable across JSON parsers (some will choke, some will give you only the value of the last occurrence) and not *useful* in any case. Use arrays of objects for the values of those date keys, not individual objects:

```
{
    "2016-06-29": [{
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    }],
    "2016-09-16": [{
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    }, {
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    }],
    "2016-09-15": [{
        "available": "1",
        "bind": 0,
        "info": "",
        "notes": "",
        "price": "",
        "promo": "",
        "status": "booked"
    }]
}
```

*(Data shortened for clarity.)*

In the above, note how `2016-06-29` and `2016-09-15` have arrays with just one entry, but `2016-09-16` has an array with two entries.